# Putting Mapbox in React-Starter-Kit

Tags: mapbox, react-starter-kit

Putting Mapbox in React-Starter-Kit , Im having trouble implementing MapBox in react-starter-kit. I dont know how I could make a component out of a client.

[Im using this for npm package of mapbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox)

I wish I could do

```
 MapBoxComponent extends Component{


static propTypes = {
    path: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string,
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
 }
```

Is this possible?

Disclaimer: This is my first time actually, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of React components that wrap mapbox.js and [mapboxgl-js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/):

- [react-mapbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapboxmap)
- [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl)
- [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet)

Here is a related discussion on github: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/951